# OCaml how to access the elements of a list in type definitions

Tags: ocaml

```
type int_list = { a : int list};;

let check = {a = [1;2;3;4]};;

let test1 = [5;10;11;2;8];;

let rec compare check input =
  match input with
  | [] -> false
  | h :: t -> 
    (* *)
;;

compare check test1;;
```

I want to iterate through `test1` and return `true` if an element is in type check list a.
Struggling with how I can start.

Comment: Do you have at least an algorithm in mind? If you know how to iterate through a list the solution should be quite straight-forward.

Comment: I know how to iterate through a list but I'm not sure how I can iterate through list inside type.

Comment: it looks like you are looking inside a record value, but not a type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a function that handles a list, say, for example:

```
let f l = match l with
  | [] -> false
  | h :: t -> true
```

Then you can call it over anything that is a list. In your case, your second list is in a record so you just have to call your function over the field of this record:

```
type int_list = { a : int list};;

let check = {a = [1;2;3;4]};;

let () = Printf.printf "%b\n" (f check.a)
```

With this in mind I hope you can find your solution or I'll be happy to give you clues in comment.